# For any measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$, are all weighted counting measures purely atomic?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have been given the following definitions:

A measure $\mu$ is a **weighted counting measure** on $(X,\mathscr{M})$ if there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ such that $$\forall E\in\mathscr{M}, \mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} f(x)$$

A non-null set $A\in\mathscr{M}$ is **$\mu$-atomic** if for each $B\in\mathscr{M}$ with $B\subseteq A$, either $\mu(B)=0$ or $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$.  If every non-null $E\in\mathscr{M}$ contains an atom then we say $\mu$ is **purely atomic**

My professor proposed the following problem as just something fun to think about, not as a real homework question:

For any measurable space $(X,\mathscr{M})$, are all weighted counting measures purely atomic?

After some thought, I believe that this question reduces to the case when $\mu$ is a finite measure, but I am struggling to make much further progress.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm confused. A set containing one element, say $A = \{x\}$, is always an $\mu$-atomic. With this definition, it seems that almost any measure will satisfy the "purely atomic" definition, or perhaps none if you allow empty sets.

Comment: @Surge Atoms are usually required to have nonzero measure

Comment: To check the definition of a purely atomic measure, we should exclude the null sets. This problem might become easier for you if you consider $\mu=\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\cdot\delta_x$

Comment: You should probably demand that $E$ contains an atom only if it is not a null set. Otherwise, the Dirac measure on the Borel sigma algebra would not be purely atomic.

Comment: @FShrike My apologies.  You are correct in stating the atoms should be required to be non-null and that we should exclude null sets when checking the definition of purely atomic.  I will update the definition accordingly